# Use apa7 for style but revtex4-2 for citation

Tags: revtex, apa7

In some school assignment, professor request paper write in APA style layout. However, request American Physics Society Citation Style. APS have revtex4-2 package to handle the ciatation, but it will also change the layout to APS style (which banned from professor).

Is there anyway I can only use citation style from revtex4-2, and keeep use apa7 for my layout? If not, anyway to put biblatex/bibtex in APS citation style to work with apa7?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about what exactly you're doing. E.g., are you using the `apa7` document class? If not, which document class do you employ?

Comment: Yes, apa7 type document.
`\documentclass[stu, 12pt, letterpaper]{apa7}`

Answer (score 1):

`revtex-2` is a LaTeX document class. As such, it can handle many different citation call-out styles and bibliography formatting requirements.

Unfortunately, you haven't indicated *which* citation call-out style is required -- numeric? author-year? author-numerical? something else? -- and how the bibliographic entries should be formatted. (The American Physics Society (APS) has published several bibliography styles over the years.) So I'll assume you're supposed to create numeric-style citation call-outs and that the bibliographic entries are supposed to be formatted according to the `apsrev` bib style.

Here's a screenshot of the bibliography page that's produced by the sample program posted below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[stu, 12pt, letterpaper, 
               colorlinks, allcolors=blue % optional
              ]{apa7}

% create a sample bib file "on the fly"
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{aa:3001, author="Anne Author", title="Thoughts", year=3001}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev} % select a suitable bibliography style

\title{ZZZZ}
\shorttitle{Z} % required information for 'apa7' class

\begin{document}
\cite{aa:3001}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how much has changed, but `apsrev.bst` is from revtex4 (c. 2000), vs `apsrev4-2.bst` is currently the latest.

Comment: @DaiBowen - Thanks for this.